# System Clock lags behind by a few minutes over a few days despite chaging BIOS battery

Tags: bios, battery, date-time

I have a Windows 7 desktop PC with Gigabyte 880GM motherboard purchased sometime in 2013.
Off lately I noticed that the system clock somewhat lags behind the actual time by about 5 - 10 minutes over a period of 2 - 3 days.

Obviously I suspected it to be weak BIOS battery and I replaced it with a Sony 3V CR2032 battery. The last time I changed it was sometime in 2015.

Despite putting in a brand new battery I am getting the same result. After about 2 - 3 days the system clock runs behind by about 5 - 10 minutes.

Note that in Windows settings it's just set to the correct region and my region does not observe any Daylight Saving just in case it matters. Also auto sync with Internet time option is Off.

Did I get a duplicate non genuine battery or does it mean that the clock chip on my board is now failing?
I am also going to buy a relatively more expensive Duracell CR 2032 just in case that would matter.

Is there anything else I can try to attempt to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why not enable auto sync and it will fix itself when it has internet access?

Comment: For unknown reasons, Internet Time Sync gives timeout error most of the times, hence I have turned it off. The lag is now evident in absence of external time sync as well.

Comment: What NTP / Internet Time sync server are you using? Have you tried using different ones (Win7 has several different ones - try all of them, or put a different server altogether that you know is working)

Answer (score 0):

The RTC (Real Time Clock) could be thrown off by an undervolting CMOS battery. Or the RTC itself could be bad. Those are integrated into the motherboard's southbridge. Nothing you could do apart from trying to replace the battery again or replacing the motherboard.