# Computer date/time lagging behind

Tags: windows, date-time

A work colleague's computer is having an unusual problem. Whenever the computer is restarted the time and gets set to approximately 1.5 days previous. The timezone is set correctly, but the computer does not connect to the internet to sync the time anyway. I figure if it was a CMOS/battery problem the time would reset to the manufacture date or 1970 or something. Why does it want to always lag behind by more than 24 hours?

It is a Windows 8 laptop.

UPDATE:
Before it seemed that it was going back 1.5 days. But now as I am investigating and restarting the computer I see it is more complicated. I can't make sense of it to explain what it is doing. It is not simply running slow. When the computer is on the clock seems to proceed at the correct pace. Just now when I restarted twice it reset to 11:50am, even though I let the clock run to 11:51 in between. Just prior to that it seemed like the time fell behind by about 30 minutes in the space of just about 15 minutes while installing updates.

Comment: When set the right time and restart and enter the BIOS is the time already wrong there or does it become wrong during the windows startup process?

Comment: It looks like it is already wrong in the BIOS. But it also looks more complicated than I stated. It looks like the time is slowly falling behind or maybe jumping back in time after a restart.

Comment: So is the clock just slow or is it actually "jumping" to a time prior to the one it showed the last time?

Comment: That is difficult to say. See my update in the question.

Comment: "When the computer is on the clock seems to proceed at the correct pace" -- So it never "jumps" during normal OS operation, a restart is the trigger, right? Please confirm. Does it happen also when the motherboard restarts while powered all the time? (fans spinning etc.); or does it require the PSU to cut the power, if only for few seconds? Have you replaced the battery anyway? Does booting live CD Linux affect the issue? Is there any correlation between the moment you set the right time and the time it "jumps" to later after restart?

Comment: To me it seems that the cmos clock is acting up (mainly running slow, maybe other effects as well) try to do more tests like running the windows or just the bios for a while to see what happens, run in bios reset and just boot into bios again etc. Meanwhile I write you a couple of possible solutions in an answer...

Comment: Actually, when I open the BIOS to look at the time it doesn't change. It shows a static time. That is not normal I guess? I don't see any correlation between anything. I see no logic to it. It seems like when we are looking at the clock in Windows it runs fine, and then some time when we are not looking it messes up. I haven't been able to exhaustively test it, but I feel like if the computer sleeps or restarts, even with power connected all the time it will probably start lagging and the amount it falls back corresponds roughly to the amount of time that Windows is not actively running.

Comment: My guess it is a problem like the one mentioned in this question https://superuser.com/questions/1296057/system-clock-lags-behind-by-a-few-minutes-over-a-few-days-despite-chaging-bios-b?rq=1. I will see if I can get the battery replaced. If it is a motherboard problem, then I think we are hooped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cmos clock is running slow or behaving strange, most common causes are:

- CMOS battery is starting to fail or failed. If it can be replaced try to check the connections and/or replace it.
- Virus infection of the OS. Check it by running a fresh operating system to see if makes a difference try to run the system just with the BIOS
- Defective/failing mainboard components or corrupted ones (e.g. through a virus). You can check [here](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/mbsys/mobo/comp_Battery.htm) for several approaches to check further battery and mainboard issues

Of course without further investigating the source it's difficult to give you a specific working solution, but maybe one of the suggestions above already helps.

Comment: My guess is it is the battery or the motherboard or the connection between them. We do have anti-virus software, which claims everything is running fine. And I think the problem happens outside of Windows.

Comment: @Moss I myself would troubleshoot a little more, but just changing the battery might be the quickest fix (if it's really the problem).

Comment: It was in fact the battery :) I guess it wasn't totally dead, but just dying.

Comment: @Moss thanks for the feedback, I adjusted my answer accordingly